# Multiple select statement with order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID IN (SELECT REQUEST_FROM FROM REQUESTS WHERE REQUEST_TO = '$user_id' ORDER BY REQUEST_ID ASC);
```

This statement returns the user informations from users table, where user's id is in REQUEST_FROM.

I also have REQUEST_DATE in REQUESTS table. I would like to order the results of this statement by REQUEST_DATE.

I don't know if this information is enough for you. I can give extra information about sql.

Comment: What is the nature of the relationship between USERS and REQUESTS tables? is it "0,1" or "0,n"?

Comment: one to many I guess.

Comment: If you have a user who did many requests with different values of REQUEST_DATE, which value of REQUEST_DATE wish you use to order the user's list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM USERS u , REQUESTS r
WHERE (r.REQUEST_TO = '$user_id') and (u.USER_ID = r.REQUEST_FROM)
ORDER BY r.REQUEST_DATE ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an explicit `join` instead of `in`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM USERS u JOIN
     REQUESTS r
     ON u.USER_ID = r.REQUEST_FROM 
WHERE r.REQUEST_TO = '$user_id'
ORDER BY r.REQUEST_DATE ASC;
```

Comment: ORDER BY r.REQUEST_DATE ASC;

Comment: Yeah I made it that too but didn't work. returns empty.